# Exclude one sheet from being looped through by VBA Macro code

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet, exclude-constraint

I want to exclude 1 worksheet from being looped in the code, how do I go about adding/doing that? I want to exclude my mailing list from being run through the code ("WB Mailling List"). I've tried a couple different suggestions that I found in different forums, but none really seemed to have work for me. Is there a simple and easy way to exclude one sheet from being looped through? I'm new to vba, so could really use the help! Thank you!

```
Option Explicit
Sub Main_AllWorksheets()
Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long, shtsRotations As String
Dim shtsFunctions As String, shtsOK As String
Dim shtsManufacture As String


For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If Application.CountIf(sh.Range("O3:O70"), "<1") > 0 Then
        shtsRotations = shtsRotations & vbLf & sh.Name
    Else
        shtsOK = shtsOK & vbLf & sh.Name & " (Rotations)"
    End If

    If Application.CountIf(sh.Range("P3:P70"), "<1") > 0 Then
        shtsFunctions = shtsFunctions & vbLf & sh.Name
    Else
        shtsOK = shtsOK & vbLf & sh.Name & " (Functions)"
    End If

    
     If Application.CountIf(sh.Range("Q3:Q70"), "<1") > 0 Then
        shtsManufacture = shtsManufacture & vbLf & sh.Name
    Else
        shtsOK = shtsOK & vbLf & sh.Name & " (Manufacturing Date)"
    End If

Next sh
 Dim myDataRng As Range


Set myDataRng = Worksheets("WB Mailing List").Range("A1:Z100" & Cells(Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row)

Dim cell As Range
Dim iCnt As Integer
Dim sMail_ids As String


For Each cell In myDataRng
    If Trim(sMail_ids) = "" Then
        sMail_ids = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value
    Else
        sMail_ids = sMail_ids & vbCrLf & ";" & cell.Offset(1, 0).Value
    End If
Next cell


Set myDataRng = Nothing         ' Clear the range.


If Len(shtsRotations) > 0 Then
    SendReminderMail sMail_ids, "Equipment rotations are due!", _
           "Hello Team, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
           "Check customer sheets: " & shtsRotations & vbLf & vbNewLine & _
           "In the attatched workbook, you can see what equipment needs to be rotated by the red dates, indicating their last rotation."

End If



If Len(shtsFunctions) > 0 Then
    SendReminderMail sMail_ids, "Equipment functions are due! ", _
           "Hello Team, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
           "Check customer sheets: " & shtsFunctions & vbLf & vbNewLine & _
           "In the attatched workbook, you can see what equipment needs to be functioned by the red dates, indicating their last function."
End If

If Len(shtsManufacture) > 0 Then
    SendReminderMail sMail_ids, "Manufacturing date has surpassed 3 years!", _
           "Hello Team, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
           "Check customer sheets: " & shtsRotations & vbLf & vbNewLine & _
           "In the attatched workbook, you can see what equipment has reached it's 3 years past manufacturing."
End If


If Len(shtsOK) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "These sheets are OK: " & vbLf & shtsOK, vbInformation
End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: `If sh.name <> "WB Mailling List" Then` as the first line inside the loop and another `End If` as the last line in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should catch the sheet by name or id to skip it.

- add this line after For ...

  If Not sh.Name="WB Mailing List" Then  ... End If

Please, change your For statement to this:

```
 For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not sh.Name="WB Mailing List" Then
      If Application.CountIf(sh.Range("O3:O70"), "<1") > 0 Then
          shtsRotations = shtsRotations & vbLf & sh.Name
      Else
          shtsOK = shtsOK & vbLf & sh.Name & " (Rotations)"
      End If

      If Application.CountIf(sh.Range("P3:P70"), "<1") > 0 Then
          shtsFunctions = shtsFunctions & vbLf & sh.Name
      Else
          shtsOK = shtsOK & vbLf & sh.Name & " (Functions)"
      End If

    
      If Application.CountIf(sh.Range("Q3:Q70"), "<1") > 0 Then
          shtsManufacture = shtsManufacture & vbLf & sh.Name
      Else
          shtsOK = shtsOK & vbLf & sh.Name & " (Manufacturing Date)"
      End If
   End if
Next sh
```

Comment: Don't know if that's why it was voted down and I'm not the man, but you really should avoid `Goto` when a simple `if...then` will do the job.

Comment: This is not a rule to avoid goto. This is my solution.

Comment: And it is probably the opinion of the voter that goto is not the proper method to use here.  A vote whether up or down is an expression of perceived quality. See: https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/Learn/Blogs/Blog-Details/ArtMID/10198/ArticleID/15289/Why-should-GOTO-be-avoided  It is the major opinion of most coders that using goto where a simply If Then block can be used is a poor practice.

Comment: it is even stated in Microsofts documentation that it should be avoided if possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/goto-statement

Comment: Ok, there is no goto))

Comment: I don't think you should use `Not` when no objects are involved. I mean, you have a simple solution:  `If sh.Name <> "WB Mailing List" Then`. Also, if you want to allow case-insensitivity (e.g. `A = a`) which is the 'natural behavior' when dealing with worksheet names, you could use [StrComp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function) and do: `If StrComp(sh.Name, "WB Mailing List", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then`.

Comment: Thank you all very much! Problem solved!! :)